# Im getting error "Type Storage does not have 'ɵmod' propert" in IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run my ionic project but I'm getting the error "**core.js:1023 Uncaught Error: Type Storage does not have 'ɵmod' property**".
I'm trying to solve this error but I am not succeding.
Please give me some solution.
Thank You.

Comment: Please post the code where this is failing

Answer (score 1):

For me I had the same probably for you. I was importing in app.module.ts both *Storage* and *IonicStorageMode*. I only needed to add Storage as a deps property

Solution: Remove **Storage** from imports.

Comment: I had copied the imports from a previous test file. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Ionic 5 or higher? (Please specify used version in the future it makes helping easier)

You might have forgotten to update the import for the storage package in app.modules like described in the [docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage), because the same thing happened to me.

Note: pay attention to the new import: @ionic/storage-angular

```js
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```